# Git on android studio pathspec error?

Tags: java, android, git, bash

I've got some problems with my git on Android Studio.
For some reason, git renames the filename of my files to lowercase.

So then when i try to push or pull them, i've got an error, every time.

Here's the message of my error :

> Commit failed with error: pathspec
>   'app/src/main/java/org/cyberflow/georapport/models/Releve.java' did
>   not match any file(s) known to git. error: pathspec
>   'app/src/main/java/org/cyberflow/georapport/models/Photo.java' did not
>   match any file(s) known to git.

I've tryed going to bash mode and add the files manually too, doesn't seem to help either.

Any idea why this happens ?

Comment: Btw, I try to be carefull when committing files by just selecting the worked files to push because if commit the project directory it pushe's all the gradle files, etc to the rest of my team and occurs SDK path problems too.

Comment: How do you know they are renamed to lowercase? Did you check at the console? Also, what OS is that?

Comment: On the file tree in Android studio the names are in lowercase

Found some sort of "workaround" by deleting the conflict files, commiting pushing. Then recreate the clean files and commiting and pushing them again